# C# set get, why value does not set?

Tags: c#, get, set

Why doesn't this code set the value? what am I doing wrong here?

```
public string databaseFolder
{
    set
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(configPath);
        XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//Settings/DatabaseFolder");
        node.InnerText = databaseFolder;
        xmldoc.Save(configPath);
    }
    get
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(configPath);
        XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//Settings/DatabaseFolder");
        return node.InnerText;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the property `databaseFolder` in your `set`. Instead of:

```
node.InnerText = databaseFolder;
```

It should be:

```
node.InnerText = value;
```

I am not really sure why you are using your property like that. You are better of extracting this logic to your methods instead of utilizing setters and getters.

Comment: Thanks alot, dunno how i missed that.